# Is there any mechanism in .NET so we can refresh/recreate singleton object on specific interval

Tags: .net, authentication, certificate, bearer-token

MY scenario is For service client I am creating singleton object on application startup. Once singleton object of service client created, will be used same till next new deployment. Inside Service Client I am fetching certificate from keyvault, So my ask is that is there any scenario exist so i can refresh service client object in every 3 month so it will get renewed certificate.

Please suggest best solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

The singleton needs to know when to refresh its internals.

on the creation of the singleton need to set the "refresh Date" (from Db?)
on every usage, you need to validate if it is the time to update the key from the keyvault.
after you get the new key from the keyvault , update the "refresh Date" (to Db ?)